# @author tag for javadoc missing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, javadoc

I have migrated from Eclipse (ADT) to Android Studio but it's saying that @author is an invalid tag for javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to create @author tag within command line. Then only you can see the results. Like this:

```
    /**
    * @author author_name
    */
```

Between `/**` and `*/`, if you type the `@` symbol and then click `ctrl+space`, all available tags will be shown automatically in android studio.

If before a method definition you type `/**` then click ENTER,   parameters and return type of method 
tags with names will be shown automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure what "parameters and return type of method tags with names" means - do you mean "method tags for the parameters and return type"?